# singly linked list error while adding a node

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

My problem is that, when i try to add a node to my singly linked list for the first time, everything goes expected, but when i want to add another node, my program crashes. Seems like my error is caused by trying to write to 0 address. however i can't seem to find the error in my code. am i using malloc right ?
Here is the code :

```
typedef struct linkedList
{
    int StudentId;
    char name[100];
    char dep[100];
    struct linkedList *next;
} LinkedList;

LinkedList *head = NULL;
LinkedList *current = NULL;

LinkedList *createList(int val, char name[], char dep[])
{
    LinkedList *ptr = (LinkedList *)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Node Creation Failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr ->StudentId = val;
    strcpy(ptr -> name, name);
    strcpy(ptr ->dep, dep);
    ptr ->next = NULL;
    head = current = ptr;
    return ptr;
}

LinkedList *addToList (int val, char name[], char dep[])
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return (createList(val, name, dep));
    }
    else
    {
        LinkedList *ptr = (LinkedList *)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
        if (ptr = NULL)
        {
            printf("Node Creation Failed\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        ptr -> StudentId = val;
        strcpy(ptr ->name, name);
        strcpy(ptr ->dep, dep);
        ptr -> next = NULL;
        current -> next = ptr;
        current = ptr;
        return ptr;
}
```

}

in main function:
AddtoList(10,"abc","abc");
calls createList, no problem but
If i use AddtoList again, program crashes, createList and AddtoList are really similar to each other, can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Did you debug your code by using a debugger, stepping through each line while oberving the relevant variables? I doubt it. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (ptr = NULL)
```

to

```
if (ptr == NULL)
```

In your case, `ptr` is assigned to `NULL` and expression within if is evaluated to `0`. Control goes to `ptr -> StudentId = val;`. It tries to access write protected memory, hence the crash.

Comment: I'm surprised OP's compiler didn't throw a warning at this point. It might be good practice to try and force the LHS to be an RVALUE instead of an LVALUE. It prevents this kind of thing from ever occurring. ie: Use this general form: `if (NULL == ptr)`.